# Efficiently get ID array of relation

Tags: laravel, eloquent

How can I efficiently get the keys of associated models?

```
class Account extends Model
{

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('\App\User', 'account_id', 'id');
    }

    /**
     * @return integer[]
     */
    public function getUserIds()
    {
            return $this->users()->getQuery()->select('id')->pluck('id');
    }
```

Is that efficient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just:

```
return $this->users()->pluck('id');
```